# Raw use of parameterized class - when returning base class with generic parameter with factory design pattern

Tags: java, generics, factory, parameterized-types

**Background**

I learned **Factory** pattern, and the power of generics and I'm attempting to piece them together.

Here are my efforts

*Without generic input parameter* - No warnings

```
public abstract class ArtifactCreator {
    public abstract void setArtifacts(String workflowInput);
}
```

---

```
public class FooArtifactCreator extends ArtifactCreator {

    @Override
    public void setArtifacts(String input) {
        return null;

    }
}
```

---

```
public class BarArtifactCreator extends ArtifactCreator {
    @Override
    public void setArtifacts(String input) {
        return null;

    }
}
```

---

```
public class Factory {
    public ArtifactCreator getArtifactCreator(String domain) {
        if (domain == "foo") {
            return new FooArtifactCreator()
        } else if (domain == "bar") {
            return new BarArtifactCreator()
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My whole problem is the `workflowInput` is relegated to the type `String`. But I want it to be some generic POJO.

*With generics* - I get warnings in `Factory.java` and `Store.java` that I want to get rid of correctly. (I want to be using generics for my use-case the right way).

1. `Raw use of parameterized class 'ArtifactCreator'` on both the files in `Store.java` and `Factory.java`
2. `Unchecked call to 'setArtifacts(T)' as a member of raw type 'ArtifactCreator'`  in `Store.java`

   public abstract class ArtifactCreator {
   public abstract void setArtifacts(T workflowInput);
   }

---

```
public class FooArtifactCreator extends ArtifactCreator<FooInput> {

    @Override
    public void setArtifacts(FooInput input) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class BarArtifactCreator extends ArtifactCreator<BarInput> {
    @Override
    public void setArtifacts(BarInput input) {
        return null;

    }
}
```

---

```
public class Factory {
    public ArtifactCreator getArtifactCreator(String domain) {
        if (domain == "foo") {
            return new FooArtifactCreator()
        } else if (domain == "bar") {
            return new BarArtifactCreator()
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Input {
    private String domain;
    private String otherInput;
}
```

---

```
public class Store {

    private final Factory factory;
    public Store(Factory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public ArtifactCreator getCaseClosureArtifactFactory(Input req) {
        ArtifactCreator artifactCreator = factory.setArtifacts(req.getDomain());

        //In reality - Create either FooInput or BarInput depending on 
        //`otherInput` field in `Input` POJO. Assume that there will be another 
        //factory/HashMap to return the input needed

        FooInput input = new FooInput();
        artifactCreator.setArtifacts(input);
    }

}
```

One way I can think of solving my problems is do something like:

```
public class WorkflowInput {
    private FooInput input;
    private BarInput input;
}



public abstract class ArtifactCreator {
    public abstract void setArtifacts(WorkflowInput workflowInput);
}


public class FooArtifactCreator extends ArtifactCreator {

    @Override
    public void setArtifacts(WorkflowInput input) {
        FooInput input = input.getFooInput(); //Extract specific input

    }
}

public class BarArtifactCreator extends ArtifactCreator {
    @Override
    public void setArtifacts(WorkflowInput input) {
        BarInput input = input.getBarInput(); //Extract specific input

    }
}
```

This feels a bit unecessary to keep some fields in `WorkflowInput` null.

Comment: `domain == "foo"` - you should use `"foo".equals(domain)` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513935#513935

Comment: Have another read of https://www.baeldung.com/java-factory-pattern-generics and note how the Class is passed in as a parameter, not a String. == comparison is acceptable for a Class type. Then, the requestor (user of the factory) should know whether it has `BarInput` or `FooInput` available and request from the factory a suitable `ArtifactCreator` for that input.